# mashape unirest java Future HttpResponse asJsonAsync cannot find symbol

Tags: java, asynchronous, asynccallback, unirest

I'm a newbie to mashape unirest, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using maven to use unirest as a dependency, as so:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next, I'm trying to use unirest to make an asyncronous call to my server using java anonymous callbacks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.async.Callback;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options;


public class CRDTClient {

    private ArrayList<String> servers;
    public AtomicInteger successCount;

    public CRDTClient() {

        servers = new ArrayList(3);
        servers.add("http://localhost:3000");
        servers.add("http://localhost:3001");
        servers.add("http://localhost:3002");
    }

    public boolean put(long key, String value) {
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(servers.size());
        successCount = new AtomicInteger();

        for (final String serverUrl : servers) {
            Future<HttpResponse<JsonNode>> future = Unirest.post(serverUrl + "/cache/{key}/{value}")
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .routeParam("key", Long.toString(key))
                    .routeParam("value", value).asJson()
                    .asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() {

                        public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                            System.out.println("The request has failed: " + serverUrl);
                            countDownLatch.countDown();
                        }

                        public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> response) {
                            int code = response.getStatus();
                            if (code == 200) {
                                successCount.incrementAndGet();
                            }

                            countDownLatch.countDown();
                        }

                        public void cancelled() {
                            System.out.println("The request has been cancelled");
                        }

                    });
        }

        // Block the thread until all responses gotten
        countDownLatch.await();

        return (Math.round(successCount.floatValue() / servers.size()) == 1);
    }
```

The error I get when I run

```
mvn clean package -e
```

is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/jonguan/Documents/SJSU/cmpe273/cmpe273-lab4/client/src/main/java/edu/sjsu/cmpe/cache/client/CRDTClient.java:[40,20] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project client: Compilation failure
.../cmpe/cache/client/CRDTClient.java:[40,20] error: cannot find symbol
```

which turns out to be the line on .asJsonAsync

I tried importing all sorts of classes, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Stupid me.

On the line previous, there is an extra .`asJson`

```
.routeParam("value", value).asJson()
```

should just be

```
.routeParam("value", value)
```